# Fluent NHibrnate - Virtual calls in constructor -Best Practice

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have an entity declared similar to this:

```
public class Comment 
{
  public Comment(string text, DateTime creationDate, string authorEmail)
  {
    Text = text;
    CreationDate = creationDate;
    AuthorEmail = authorEmail;
  }

  public virtual string Text { get; private set; }
  public virtual DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
  public virtual string AuthorEmail { get; private set; }
}
```

I have taken it from [Is it OK to call virtual properties from the constructor of a NHibernate entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465436/is-it-ok-to-call-virtual-properties-from-the-constructor-of-a-nhibernate-entity)

I get warning as 'Virtual Calls in constructor'.

Though, it doesn't pose any practical issue because virtual members are declared solely for NH to proxy. However, I was wondering if I should move the constructor method to a new *factory* class with new method being declared as

```
CreateComment(string text, DateTime creationDate, string authorEmail)
```

What will be the best practice in this case?

Please note that currently I have 4-5 overloaded constructors in my domain entity. Above is just an example.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have tested with FluentNHibernate, you can do it like this:

```
public class Comment
{
    private string _text;
    private DateTime _creationDate;
    private string _authorEmail;

    public Comment(string text, DateTime creationDate, string authorEmail)
    {
        _text = text;
        _creationDate = creationDate;
        _authorEmail = authorEmail;
    }

    public virtual string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        private set { _text = value; }
    }

    public virtual DateTime CreationDate
    {
        get { return _creationDate; }
        set { _creationDate = value; }
    }

    public virtual string AuthorEmail
    {
        get { return _authorEmail; }
        private set { _authorEmail = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer having a parameterless (default) constructor and constructing like so:

```
var comment = new Comment {
                  Text = "Something offensive and political.",
                  CreationDate = DateTime.Now,
                  AuthorEmail = "someonestupidwithanopinion17@aol.com"
              };
```

Now the issue doesn't matter.

Comment: what about the method where I need to pass values from outside: (string text, DateTime creationDate, string authorEmail)

Comment: @iniki: Huh? I don't understand what you mean because you can simply say `var comment = new Comment { Text = GetText(), CreationDate = GetCreationDate(), AuthorEmail = GetAuthorEmail() };`

Comment: I am sorry Jason, but I think I am missing your point here :-( Actually the overloaded constructors that I have right now need to set object members to values that I receive from client application. Not sure how can I do that in a parameterless constructor. Could you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: Jason I think you've missed the point that those properties are read-only. your code won't compile.

Comment: @iniki, sJhonny: You're right, I completely overlooked that. Why are you making the setters private?

Answer (score 0):

If your properties are only virtual to accomodate nHibernate, you can just make them encapsulate concrete fields (nhibernate knows how to cope with that: see [here](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-mapping) (default-access) and [here](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-property) (access).
it's supported in fluent nh as well.