# Nhibernate and Concurrency

Tags: nhibernate, concurrency, transactions

What's the best way to make this test application to run concurrently?

When my program has finished, the console application prints the employee count as `4057`. It should be `20000` because I have `20` threads incrementing the employee count `1000` times.

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DataAccess;
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Cfg;
using NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl;

namespace NhibernatePlayground
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
        private static Configuration _configuration;
        private static int TotalThreadCount = 20;
        private static int LoopCount = 1000;

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            _configuration = BuildConfiguration();
            var se = new SchemaExport(_configuration);
            se.Drop(true, true);
            se.Create(false, true);


            _sessionFactory = _configuration.BuildSessionFactory();

            int companyId = Seed();

            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            Task[] tasks = new Task[TotalThreadCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < TotalThreadCount; i ++)
            {
                tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => IncreaseEmployeeCount(LoopCount, companyId));
            }

            //Block until all tasks complete.
            Task.WaitAll(tasks);
            sw.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("Employee Count: " + GetEmployeeCount(companyId));
            Console.WriteLine("Total Milliseconds: " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static Configuration BuildConfiguration()
        {
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.Configure(); // A
            configuration.AddAssembly(typeof (Company).Assembly); // B            
            return configuration;
        }

        private static void IncreaseEmployeeCount(int count, int companyId)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                using (ISession _session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession())
                {
                    using (ITransaction _transaction = _session.BeginTransaction())
                    {
                        var company = _session.Get<Company>(companyId);
                        company.EmployeeCount++;
                        _session.Save(company);
                        _transaction.Commit();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static int Seed()
        {
            using (ISession _session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession())
            {
                using (ITransaction _transaction = _session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    Company company = new Company
                        {
                            CompanyName = "Angus"
                        };

                    _session.Save(company);
                    _transaction.Commit();
                    return company.Id;
                }
            }
        }

        private static int GetEmployeeCount(int companyId)
        {
            using (ISession _session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession())
            {
                using (ITransaction _transaction = _session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    Company company = _session.Get<Company>(companyId);
                    return company.EmployeeCount;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Company.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="DataAccess" namespace="DataAccess" >

  <class name="Company">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="hilo" />
    </id>

    <property name="IsActive" />

    <property name="CompanyName" />

    <property name="EmployeeCount" />

    <set name="Users" table="Users_Companies" cascade="none">
      <key column="CompanyId"/>
      <many-to-many column="UserId" class="UserProfile" />
    </set>    
  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Company.cs**

```
using Iesi.Collections.Generic;

namespace DataAccess
{
    public class Company : Entity<int>
    {
        public Company()
        {
            //it's not the best practice to initialize virtual properties in constructor but we're controlling 
            //the inheritance in this so doing this should be fine
            // http://stackoverflow.com/a/469577/89605
            Users = new HashedSet<UserProfile>();
        }

        public Company(string name)
            : this()
        {
            CompanyName = name;
            IsActive = true;
        }

        public virtual string CompanyName { set; get; }

        public virtual bool IsActive { set; get; }

        public virtual ISet<UserProfile> Users { set; get; }

        public virtual int EmployeeCount { set; get; }

        public virtual void CopyTo(Company target)
        {
            target.CompanyName = CompanyName;
            target.IsActive = IsActive;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is really about NHibernate. Increments (get + set) are inherently thread-unsafe. Guess your only option is synchronizing the `IncreaseEmployeeCount` call (by using a lock or a mutex, for example).

Comment: As you tried IsolationLevel.Serializable in almost the same question ( http://stackoverflow.com/q/15484204/1236044 ), it seems you're trying different isolation levels types. You may give a try to IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead

Comment: @rsenna I have read some where (but forgot where) that using locks are not recommended but I could be wrong.

Comment: @jbl Yes I have tried using  IsolationLevel.Serializable and SQL Server encountered a deadlock. I didnt take a detail look at the deadlock graph but I assume it has something to do with the fact multiple threads are trying to upgrade from read locks to write locks.

Comment: @burnt1ce If you need a lock, clearly it would be a bad idea to avoid it. I think the point is that locks can have a negative impact on performance, and lead to deadlocks, so it's better if we can design code to not need them. But if we do have shared data, some sort of synchronization mechanism is unavoidable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to grab a write-lock in the database while reading the object. Explore the lock mode parameter to Get(), or the ISession.Lock() method. This would be pessimistic locking, which would be appropriate for a scenario like this (frequent writes to the same data). The alternative is optimistic locking, which works best when there are infrequent writes to the same data. For that, explore NHibernate's <version> mapping element.